# Save hashmap to String using lambda expressions

Tags: java, lambda, hashmap, java-8

I am trying to save the output of the following code in a string variable called "output". However, I get this compile error "Local variable output defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final". I did try to declare the output variable as final but I get another compile error "The final local variable output cannot be assigned. It must be blank and not using a compound assignment" Any suggestions, please?

```
        String output = "";
    map.entrySet().stream().sorted(
            Map.Entry.<String, Integer> comparingByValue()
            .reversed()
            .thenComparing(Map.Entry.comparingByKey()))
            .forEach(entry -> {
                output += entry.getKey() + " - " + entry.getValue();
            });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't assign a new value to a local variable from within the lambda expression (which is what happens when you use the `+=` operator on the `output` `String`). However, you can switch the `String` to a `StringBuilder` :

```
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
map.entrySet().stream().sorted(
        Map.Entry.<String, Integer> comparingByValue()
        .reversed()
        .thenComparing(Map.Entry.comparingByKey()))
        .forEach(entry -> {
            output.append(entry.getKey() + " - " + entry.getValue());
        });
```

Comment: You don’t need the curly braces for the lambda expression. And if you are appending to a `StringBuilder` it should be used consistenly rather than mixing it with the `+` operator: `.forEach(entry -> output.append(entry.getKey()).append(" - ").append(entry.getValue()))`. Besides that, I’d prefer `Collectors.joining()`…

Comment: Even if there was a reason to directly write into a StringBuilder from a stream, it would be better to use `forEachOrdered` rather than `forEach` because `StringBuilder` is not synchronized.  `forEachOrdered` would be more self-documenting and more resilient against somebody coming along and making your stream parallel.

Answer (score 6):

There is a collector for that: `joining()`.

```
String output = map.entrySet().stream()
        .sorted(Map.Entry.<String, Integer> comparingByValue()
          .reversed()
          .thenComparing(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
         )
        .map(entry -> entry.getKey() + " - " + entry.getValue())
        .collect(joining());
```

You can also add a delimiter: `joining(", ")`.

Comment: Thank you  for your answer, I did not know that there is a special method for it. Thanks! :)